# If you started iOS programming today, what frameworks would you consider still necessary and useful?

Tags: xcode, rest, ios6, xcode4.5, libraries

I've recently started iOS development, coming into it as a web developer. I couldn't imagine not using tools like jquery and modernizor. (I know plenty of other people could, but that's them)

XCode seems to have undergone some major upgrades in the past year or so, making a lot of libraries less useful.

**Example:** Plenty of tutorials recommend using JSONkit, however with the advent NSJSONSerialization, JSONkit seems to have fallen out of favor. Is this  true?

**My question is:** If you were to start developing an server backed iOS app today (April 18th, 2013), what frameworks/libraries would you recommend looking into for the simple app spec described below?

Let's say the app:

- Preforms all the regular REST functions
- Takes the JSON results and plots them on a map
- Creates listviews of the data

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple answer: learn how to use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)

It will make most of the work if you want to build the application you describe. [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial) will help you to build the app with restkit.